# Put Items in RelativeLayout dynamically

Tags: android

I have done some research, but the answer i found does not work for me. Here is some part of my code. the R.id.relative is the id of the relativelayout in the xml file

```
    RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setText(" History ");
    title.setId(99099);
    title.setTextSize(30);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    title.setLayoutParams(params);

    RL.addView(title);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams test_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button test = new Button(this);
    test.setText(" Back ");
    test_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,99099);
    test.setId(199291);
    test.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    test.setLayoutParams(test_params);

    RL.addView(test);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams test_params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button test2 = new Button(this);
    test2.setText(" Clear ");
    test_params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,test.getId());
    test2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    test.setLayoutParams(test_params2);

    RL.addView(test2);
```

all 3 items did show up, but they stack together. I can't get them below another.
Could anyone help ?

Comment: do you think Android ignores your rules - `addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,title.getId());` ?

Comment: what happens when you change title.getId() to the id value of 99099?

Comment: ya still the same,  now I am trying to put params into the addview method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The rule you have added is causing your view to be stacked together.If you need to add it should be used by the following rule.

```
    test_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 1);
```

Next, add the view to your RelativeLayout with your LayoutParams:

```
  RL.addView(yourAdView, rLParams);
```

same goes for the each cases.try to run.It will solve your problem

Comment: Does rLParams equal to test_params ? 
I should put like this : **RL.addView(Btn1,test_params);**

Comment: oh ya it worked, using addView to setup the layout is correct

Comment: Thanks for your comment..Still i got negative vote for my comment.Thanks for your appreciation

Comment: :(   I am too new here. can't give you any positive

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been able to find out, you have to add the view using LayoutParams. Here's an example:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

parentView.addView(linearLayout, relativeParams);
```

And to relatively position your items programmatically you have to assign ids to them, this stops them from 'overlapping'.

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setId(1);
TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tv2.setId(2);
```

Then `addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv1.getId());`

Comment: I am so curious about this line :  **parentView.addView(linearLayout, relativeParams);**  Does it mean i put another RelativeLayout onto my layout in the xml file.

Comment: Yes; it was just an example

Answer (score 0):

Change `test.setLayoutParams(test_params2);` to `test2.setLayoutParams(test_params2);`

Explanation: You have inadvertently set the layout params of `test` a second time, with params that instruct it to be below itself, which I guess just puts it top-left (default placement in a `RelativeLayout`). Since you never give `test2` any layout params, it also gets default placement. So everything is at the top and thus appear atop each other.

Incidentally, if you just want them arranged linearly, why not use a vertical `LinearLayout`?